# Double click events not firing

Tags: javascript, event-listener, double-click

Having some issues with double click events in JavaScript.

I want to be able to click on an element in fast succession but listen for double clicks. Is this technically possible or do I need to have a single click and listen for when it's been clicked twice?

A codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/ChronixPsyc/pen/bozmOa).

The JS can be found below too.

```
(function() {

  var el;
  var count = 0;
  var counter;

  function init() {
    el = document.getElementById('click-me');
    counter = document.getElementById('counter');

    el.addEventListener('dblclick', onDblClick, false);
  }

  function onDblClick(e) {
    count++;
    counter.textContent = count;
  }

  init();

}());
```

It seems that after double clicking on something, you need to leave a short pause to allow it to reset the event, maybe a second or half a second?

Is there something I'm missing with the dblclick event itself or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

**P.S. This only needs to work in Webkit/Chrome as this isn't for a website, but an overlay for a game.**

Comment: I can rage-click your codepen and it keeps incrementing fine. Is your problem in a particular browser / device / input method?

Comment: @Fenton While it works, it sometimes fails for me (takes 3 double clicks), running on Chrome 61.

Comment: So looks like it works in Edge, IE, and Firefox. I only really need this to work in Chrome/Webkit as this isn't specifically for a website. I'll update my question.

Comment: @ChronixPsyc According to MDN dblclick on Chrome only works **"[1] Only works for <textarea> elements and some <input> element types."** [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick)

Comment: Looks like a pause is required between double clicks. If you click too many times in a row, it would only work once. Kind of make sense though, if I clicked 4 times in a row then it's a quadruple click even though double click triggers since there is no such thing as quadruple or triple click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (https://gist.github.com/karbassi/639453):

```
(function() {

  var el;
  var count = 0;
  var counter;
  var clickCount = 0;

  function init() {
    el = document.getElementById('click-me');
    counter = document.getElementById('counter');

    el.addEventListener('click', onDblClick, false);
  }

  function onDblClick(e) {

    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount === 1) {
        singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            clickCount = 0;            
        }, 400);
    } else if (clickCount === 2) {
        count++;
        clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
        clickCount = 0;
        counter.textContent = count;
    }
}
  init();

}());
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the best solution to go with. `dblclick` doesn't look to be very consistent in the Webkit engine I'm using.